# css keyframe animation image loop

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm creating a css keyframe animation in which an image will slide-in, park for a minute, then slide-out as the next image slides in, and this will run in an 'infinite' loop (as long as there's an 'animate' class on the parent element, which is toggled via js on scroll).

What I have so far (https://jsfiddle.net/WhiskeyT/Lurkf4f6/) is presenting two problems:

First, the timings required seemed straightforward - total animation duration of 3 seconds, image 1, 2, & 3 animation-durations set to 0, 3s, 6s - but there appears to be a slight delay or gap between the exiting image and the entering image, and I'd like very much to tighten it up. Despite hours of tweaking I can't seem to tweak the keyframes into something closer to my objective.

Second issue is more substantial and obvious: the 3 images animate, and as the animation loops only the 3rd image is repeatedly loading.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Whiskey T.

```
<div class="slide" id="slide-02">
    <div class="image-rotator">
        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img" />
        <img src="img2.jpg" alt="img" />
        <img src="img3.jpg" alt="img" />
    </div>
</div><!-- #slide-02 -->


.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}


#slide-02 .image-rotator {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -450px; // I remain confused as to how init rule collides w/0% keyframe ;(
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(1) { animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 0s; }
#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(2) { animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 3s; }
#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(3) { animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 6s; }

@keyframes imgRotator {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: 450px;
    }
    15%, 84% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -450px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after the delays all the animations will be the same because the delays are multiplier of the duration so only the third one will remain visible since all of them are animating at the same states and above each other.

You may decrease the opacity and you will clearly see what is happening:

```css
.slide {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   position: relative;
}

#slide-02 .image-rotator {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid lime;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -450px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(1) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 0s;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(2) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 3s;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(3) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 6s;
}

@keyframes imgRotator {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      left: 450px;
   }
   15%,
   84% {
      opacity:0.8;
      left: 0;
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 0;
      left: -450px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide animate" id="slide-02">
   <div class="image-rotator">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/7hgn7691t/pexels-photo-39803.jpg" alt="apple" />
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/d5mxy25oh/bananas-fruit-carbohydrates-sweet-38283.jpg" alt="bananas" />
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/hrj26ejht/pexels-photo-109274.jpg" alt="cherries" />
   </div>
</div>
<!-- #slide-02 -->
```

To fix this, you may adjust the animation and the delays like this:

```css
.slide {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   position: relative;
}

#slide-02 .image-rotator {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid lime;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -450px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(1) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 0s;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(2) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 1s;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(3) {
   animation: imgRotator 3s ease-in-out infinite 2s;
}

@keyframes imgRotator {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      left: 450px;
   }
   50%{
      opacity: 1;
      left: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide animate" id="slide-02">
   <div class="image-rotator">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/7hgn7691t/pexels-photo-39803.jpg" alt="apple" >
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/d5mxy25oh/bananas-fruit-carbohydrates-sweet-38283.jpg" alt="bananas" >
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/hrj26ejht/pexels-photo-109274.jpg" alt="cherries" >
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Your suggestions indeed resolve the sequence/loop issue. But at this duration/delays the images don't pause. So I restored my keyframes (15%, etc.) the timing's off and the loop has a giant gap again. In attempt to prevent the overlap I used linear timing but with the staggered delay values the results (https://jsfiddle.net/WhiskeyT/mw9ze8wq/1/) are still off. Any insight? Perhaps you can elaborate on how to approach this, greatly appreciated

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot well, I would say there is no general rules but all depend on what you want ... the first advice i can give you is to make the animation as simple as possible then depending on the animations states make sure you don't have any overlap for the main one. In your fiddle there is no need to change the aniamtion, simply keep it as the one i show you, here is the updated : https://jsfiddle.net/mw9ze8wq/3/

Comment: Thanks again Temani. The requirement though is that the image slide in and pause for a second or so, and then slide out, so I'll have to continue to work on it because this version it's continuously moving.

Comment: You can add the pause in the @keyframes: dont animate anything between 30% and 70%

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mostly with the keyframes.

Since you have 3 children, the base span of time is 1/3 = 33%.

This span of time, must be split in 2 steps, one moving and the other still. the first and the second must sum to 33. I have set 17 for the moving step, but this is up to you.

The result:

```css
.slide {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80vh;
   position: relative;
}

#slide-02 .image-rotator {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid lime;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -450px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 3px;
   animation: imgRotator 9s ease-in-out infinite;
}


#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(2) {
   animation-delay: -3s;
}

#slide-02.animate .image-rotator img:nth-child(3) {
   animation-delay: -6s;
}

@keyframes imgRotator {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      left: 450px;
   }
   17%, 33%{
      opacity: 1;
      left: 0;
   }
   50%, 100% {    /* 33 + 17 = 50 */
      opacity: 0;
      left: -450px;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide animate" id="slide-02">
   <div class="image-rotator">
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/7hgn7691t/pexels-photo-39803.jpg" alt="apple" >
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/d5mxy25oh/bananas-fruit-carbohydrates-sweet-38283.jpg" alt="bananas" >
      <img src="https://s22.postimg.cc/hrj26ejht/pexels-photo-109274.jpg" alt="cherries" >
   </div>
</div>
```